# Kendo drop-down not opening with enter key in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-dropdown

We are using kendo drop-down list inside a kendo container and all the keys are working like alt+downarrrow to open the key and arrows to select e.t.c but when we press enter the drop-down is not opening. Could someone please help me on this.

Tried to write a custom function on enter key event but didn’t work

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/

If I look at the documentation example it works fine